# Proof of second Bianchi identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I have a problem. I thought it was second Bianchi identity at first, but it's not. I have checked again and this formula is not wrong. How to prove it?
$$R^n{}_{ikl;m}+R^n{}_{ikm;l}+R^n{}_{ilm;k}=0$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1494262/11127

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Bianchi has ${R^n}_{imk;l}$ in the second term. Are  the interchanged $k\leftrightarrow  m$ indices your problem?  The curvature tensor changes sign under this change, so it is hard to imagine that your expressions can be correct.